# Why the grid view appear different in the emulator?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, gridview

Why does the emulator have different sizes of buttons other than the designed ones here is the XML? This is a serious problem with the grid views and I've encountered it many times but I can't find the answer.

Where is the problem?

[image]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.life.braintrainer.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#26eb47"
        android:onClick="start"
        android:padding="40dp"
        android:text="Go!"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#e6ff26"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="30s"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pointsTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/timerTextView"
        android:background="#fe8a0e"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="0/0"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sumTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pointsTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="30 + 12"
        android:textColor="#312e2e"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <GridLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sumTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="#27f13f"
            android:onClick="chooseAnswer"
            android:tag="0"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="80sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="#0a2ef9"
            android:onClick="chooseAnswer"
            android:tag="1"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="80sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="#f43ffb"
            android:onClick="chooseAnswer"
            android:tag="2"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="80sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="#2cdefe"
            android:onClick="chooseAnswer"
            android:tag="3"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="80sp" />


    </GridLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Correct!"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```